# Split multi paragraphed shell output to multiple variables

Tags: shell, shell-script

I am looking to split multi paragraphed shell results into different variables,

Here's a sample output from sensors to illustrate

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

In this case I am looking to have a variable `sensors` (the command name) with the whole output,  `sensors_acpitz_virtual_0` with the whole first paragraph of output and a variable `sensors_coretemp_isa_0000` with the content of the second paragraph.

sensors_acpitz_virtual_0

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)
```

sensors_coretemp_isa_0000

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

Then a variable `sensors_acpitz_virtual_0__Adapter__Virtual_device` that will only contain the content of this part of the first paragraph

```
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)
```

A variable `sensors_acpitz_virtual_0__Adapter__Virtual_device__temp1` that will contain only the temperature of temp1 from the Virtual device adapter of acpitz-virtual-0 and so on.

```
+41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)
```

What tools (preferably commonly available pre installed in distros) should I use and how, to get this kind of results ?

Comment: Are you expecting a general solution, or those are the actual variable names that you want to create? Can you show, in your example, what should be the contents of the variables `acpitz_virtual_0__Adapter__Virtual_device` and `acpitz_virtual_0__Adapter__Virtual_device__temp1`?

Comment: If possible, a general solution, if impossible, as much detail as possible to adapt the answer to other situations with multi paragraphed outputs because I can't know what will be in the output before getting it.

Comment: As output, do you expect a shell script with those variables assigned, or to split those results into an existing shell script?

Comment: The names of the variables should be dynamically generated?

Comment: The point is to make it a function in a script, then it would allow the script to get the results by looking at what set throws up. Meaning the variable name should be dynamically generated as we don't know what awaits us

Answer (score 3):

well, i'm not really sure i get from whence the name *`acpitz_virtual_0__Adapter__Virtual_device__temp1`* is supposed to come, and so this doesn't do anything for it, but:

```
sed     -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e'x;s///' \
        -e 's/\(\n.*\)*-/_\1/g' \
        -e "s/\n\(.*\)/='\1'/" <your_input
```

...writes output as follows:

```
acpitz_virtual_0='Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)'
coretemp_isa_0000='Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)'
```

I didn't allow for any possibility of a `'` single-quote in your input, and i assume the only incompatibility with portable shell names are the dashes in each. To handle the quotes *(just in case)* do:

```
sed     -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -ex\;s/// \
        -e "s/\(\n.*\)*['-]/_\1/g" \
        -e "s/'/'"'\\&&/g'         \
        -e "s/\n\(.*\)/='\1'/" <your_input
```

...which will always escape any hardquote in input.

To use this output in the way you specify there are several options. You can wrap it in `eval`:

```
eval "$(sed ... <your_input)"
```

...or read it out to a file...

```
sed ... <your_input >out; . ./out
```

...or stream it to a subshell...

```
sed ... <your_input | sh
```

...and many other things besides.

---

Here's another `sed` that can do the fancy stuff you asked about:

```
sed -netDel -e'/./{H;g;s///'              \
-e'# grow'  -e's/[0-9]*:  .*\n[^:0-9]*//' \
-e'# loop'  -e's/:  .*//'                 \
-e'# ends'  -e's/[^_[:alnum:]]/_/g;}'     \
-e'# here'  -e's/\(.\)\(.*\)/& \\/p'      \
-e$\!t -ex  -e's//\2\1. \\/'              \
-e'# swap'  -e"s/'/'"'\\&&/g;tDel'        \
-ed\;:Del   -e"s/\(.*\). /'\1' /"         \
-e'# loop'  -e'/^[^:]*:  /!{p;D;}'        \
-e'# ends'  -e"s/\n/' \\\&/;P;D"  <infile >outfile
```

Here's how this works: `sed` kind of burns its candle at both ends here, in a manner of speaking. `sed` alternates *states* between iterative growth from left-to-right, and, at the end of each paragraph, iterative reduction in the same direction.

Kind of like:

```
1
1:2    # grow
1:2:3  # swap
  2:3  # del
    3
#if that makes any sense at all...
```

---

The *grow* state is handled between `/./{H;g;...p;};$!t`.

---

- For each input line matching at least a `.` single character, `sed` appends a copy to `H`old space, and immediately afterwards `g`ets all of the hold space by overwriting the pattern space.

  - In this way `sed` can perform edits on the growing stack and print the results for each iteration while saving the original input in hold space all the while.
- In the *grow* state, `sed` will print a valid shell name for each input line.

  - `sed` removes everything between the first and last occurrences of `"[0-9]*:  "` and everything from the last occurrence of `":  "` on, but otherwise replaces any characters which are `^`not in the class `[_[:alnum:]]` with the character `_` - and so the names grow recursively *(until they don't)*.
- `sed` `t`ests for any line which has undergone a successful edit during a *grow* state and branches those away from the script before attempting to handle logic for the *swap* state.

  - As a special case, this `t`est is `!`not performed for the `$`last input line, and so it falls-through to the *swap* state anyway.

---

The *swap* state is handled between `x;...;d`

---

- `sed` e`x`changes either the last or a blank pattern space buffer for the hold space buffer, thereby clearing the save space for the next input paragraph *(if any)*.

  - Sequences of more than a single blank-line in input do not negatively affect this pattern - exchanging a blank hold space for a blank pattern space can happen as often as is needed to arrive at identical results.
- `sed` swaps the paragraph's leading blank line to its tail, appends a space followed by a backslash, and escapes at once all single-quotes *(if any)* in the paragraph before falling through for a non-blank hold buffer to the *del* state, or else `d`eleting a blank one.

---

The *del* state is effective while `tDel -> :Del` and is handled between `:Del;...;D`.

---

- `sed` wraps all of its recursively reducing pattern buffer in a pair of single-quotes.

  - The first of these is removed with the first line for every *del* iteration, but the last is always replaced with itself.
- For a paragraph buffer matching `"^[^:]*:  "` `sed` will prepend another single quote followed by a space and a backslash to the first occurring embedded `\n`ewline in the buffer *(if any)* and `P`rint to output only the first line of the buffer.

  - Otherwise, `sed` `p`rints a not-blank buffer entirely.
- Either way, `sed` then `D`eletes up to the first occurring `\n`ewline in the buffer before cycling back to the top of the script should any remain.

  - If a buffer is not emptied here, then at the top of the script - after the first line is removed - the initial `t`est will prove true for the quote substitution just performed, and so `sed` will skip the majority of its edit script directly to the `:Del` label for each iteration of the *del* state until the buffer is emptied entirely.

---

And so `sed` *mostly* can do the fancy stuff you asked about. `sed`'s streaming nature is not excepted here, and so it writes output like:

```
acpitz_virtual_0 \
acpitz_virtual_0_Adapter__Virtual_device \
acpitz_virtual_0_Adapter__Virtual_device_temp1 \
'acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)
' \
'Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)
' \
'temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)' \
'' \
coretemp_isa_0000 \
coretemp_isa_0000_Adapter__ISA_adapter \
coretemp_isa_0000_Adapter__ISA_adapter_Core_0 \
coretemp_isa_0000_Adapter__ISA_adapter_Core_1 \
'coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
' \
'Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
' \
'Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)' \
'Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)' \
'' \
###backslashes for set or for assignment
```

... in a stack per paragraph: names first, then values. You can loop over it, and each paragraph will end in a null argument.

There's also a lot more validation going on here, and so there should be no danger of invalid shell names or unquoted output values of any kind whatever its input.

This function works with your input:

```sh
ineval(){
        . /dev/fd/0
        for     v
        do      case    ${#v}:${s:-$v}  in
                (0*)    until   [ 0 -eq "${#1}" ] &&
                        s= &&   ${1+"shift"}
                        do      shift;  done;;
                (*:*[-:]*) eval "s=- $1=\$v;shift"
        esac;   done
}       <<SET
        set ''  $(    sed -netDel -e'/./{H;g;s///'              \
                      -e'# grow'  -e's/[0-9]*:  .*\n[^:0-9]*//' \
                      -e'# loop'  -e's/:  .*//'                 \
                      -e'# ends'  -e's/[^_[:alnum:]]/_/g;}'     \
                      -e'# here'  -e's/\(.\)\(.*\)/& \\/p'      \
                      -e$\!t -ex  -e's//\2\1. \\/'              \
                      -e'# swap'  -e"s/'/'"'\\&&/g;tDel'        \
                      -ed\;:Del   -e"s/\(.*\). /'\1' /"         \
                      -e'# loop'  -e'/^[^:]*:  /!{p;D;}'        \
                      -e'# ends'  -e"s/\n/' \\\&/;P;D"     "$@" )
SET
```

Here is a `set -x` of your input:

```sh
(set -x; ineval /tmp/sens)

+ sed -netDel -e/./{H;g;s/// -e# grow -es/[0-9]*:  .*\n[^:0-9]*// -e# loop -es/:  .*// -e# ends -es/[^_[:alnum:]]/_/g;} -e# here -es/\(.\)\(.*\)/& \\/p -e$!t -ex -es//\2\1. \\/ -e# swap -es/'/'\\&&/g;tDel -ed;:Del -es/\(.*\). /'\1' / -e# loop -e/^[^:]*:  /!{p;D;} -e# ends -es/\n/' \\&/;P;D /tmp/sens
+ . /dev/fd/0
+ set  acpitz_virtual_0 acpitz_virtual_0_Adapter__Virtual_device acpitz_virtual_0_Adapter__Virtual_device_temp1 acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)
 Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)
 temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)  coretemp_isa_0000 coretemp_isa_0000_Adapter__ISA_adapter coretemp_isa_0000_Adapter__ISA_adapter_Core_0 coretemp_isa_0000_Adapter__ISA_adapter_Core_1 coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
 Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
 Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C) Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C) 
+ [ 0 -eq 0 ]
+ s=
+ shift
+ eval s=- acpitz_virtual_0=$v;shift
+ s=- acpitz_virtual_0=acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)

+ shift
+ eval s=- acpitz_virtual_0_Adapter__Virtual_device=$v;shift
+ s=- acpitz_virtual_0_Adapter__Virtual_device=Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)

+ shift
+ eval s=- acpitz_virtual_0_Adapter__Virtual_device_temp1=$v;shift
+ s=- acpitz_virtual_0_Adapter__Virtual_device_temp1=temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)
+ shift
+ [ 0 -eq 83 ]
+ shift
+ [ 0 -eq 66 ]
+ shift
+ [ 0 -eq 41 ]
+ shift
+ [ 0 -eq 0 ]
+ s=
+ shift
+ eval s=- coretemp_isa_0000=$v;shift
+ s=- coretemp_isa_0000=coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)

+ shift
+ eval s=- coretemp_isa_0000_Adapter__ISA_adapter=$v;shift
+ s=- coretemp_isa_0000_Adapter__ISA_adapter=Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)

+ shift
+ eval s=- coretemp_isa_0000_Adapter__ISA_adapter_Core_0=$v;shift
+ s=- coretemp_isa_0000_Adapter__ISA_adapter_Core_0=Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
+ shift
+ eval s=- coretemp_isa_0000_Adapter__ISA_adapter_Core_1=$v;shift
+ s=- coretemp_isa_0000_Adapter__ISA_adapter_Core_1=Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
+ shift
+ [ 0 -eq 157 ]
+ shift
+ [ 0 -eq 139 ]
+ shift
+ [ 0 -eq 58 ]
+ shift
+ [ 0 -eq 58 ]
+ shift
+ [ 0 -eq 0 ]
+ s=
+ shift
```

Comment: That's hardcorely awesome, reading the answer it looks like it is what I wanted, but I don't understand how to use the second part (managed to use your first part with the simple 3/4 sed lines and the input behind)

Comment: @Zulgrib - just use that function. any arguments you give it will work out as named `sed` input files, or else with no arguments it will just read stdin. i had your input in my clipboard, and i did `xsel | ineval` after defining the function as written. the whole thing is the function, by the way - to include the `SET` heredocument at its tail - that's all the function definition. im looking at it right now to make sure there aren't any soft-quoted `!` bangs so a psycho-shell history expansion won't backfire if you just paste it directly to a shell prompt as it...

Comment: @Zulgrib - yeah, so you can just paste the code-block w/ `ineval()` directly into a `dash` or `bash` shell prompt then press enter. then do `ineval <your_input` or `ineval -- some list of input files`. `zsh` doesn't parse the here-document correctly when i paste it to a prompt though, and im not sure why, but does work just like that with `ksh`, too. it doesn't write to stdout, though, you know - it just defines those variables.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like:

```
eval "$(#"
  perl -MString::ShellQuote -00 -lne '
    if (/^(.+)\n(.+)/) {
      ($v1, $v2, $rest) = ("sensors_$1", "$2", $'\'');
      # $v1, $v2 contain the first 2 lines, $rest the rest

      s/\W/_/g for $v1, $v2;
      # replace non-word characters with _ in the variables

      print "$v1=" . shell_quote("$1\n$2$rest");
      print "${v1}__$v2=" . shell_quote("$2$rest");
      # output the variable definition taking care to quote the value

      while ($rest =~ /^(.*?):\s*(.*)/gm) {
        # process the "foo: bar" lines in the rest
        ($v3,$val) = ("$1", $2);
        $v3 =~ s/\W/_/g;
        print "${v1}__${v2}__$v3=" . shell_quote($val)
      }
    }' < that-file)"
```

`-00` for paragraph mode. `-l` to remove the paragraph separator off the end of the records and for `print` to add one on output.

`-n` process the input one record at a time.

On your sample, that perl command will output the following shell code:

```
sensors_acpitz_virtual_0='acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)'

sensors_acpitz_virtual_0__Adapter__Virtual_device='Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)'

sensors_acpitz_virtual_0__Adapter__Virtual_device__temp1='+41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)'

sensors_coretemp_isa_0000='coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)'

sensors_coretemp_isa_0000__Adapter__ISA_adapter='Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)'

sensors_coretemp_isa_0000__Adapter__ISA_adapter__Core_0='+36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)'

sensors_coretemp_isa_0000__Adapter__ISA_adapter__Core_1='+36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)'
```

And we use `eval "$(that-perl-command)"` to tell the shell to evaluate that code output by that command.

Answer (score 1):

Perl has a special paragrph mode in which it defines "lines" as paragraphs. This means that a line is defined by two consecutive `\n`, not one. From `man perlrun`:

```
   -0[octal/hexadecimal]
        specifies the input record separator ($/) as an octal or
        hexadecimal number. [. . .]

    The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph
    mode.
```

You can therefore write a perl script that prints your variables:

```
$ perl -00lne '/.*/; $v=$&; $v=~s/-/_/g; print "$v=\"$_\""' file 
acpitz_virtual_0="acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)"

coretemp_isa_0000="coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)"
```

And then use `eval` to tell your shell to read them:

```
$ eval "$(perl -00lne '/.*/; $v=$&; $v=~s/-/_/g; print "$v=\"$_\""' file )"
$ echo "$coretemp_isa_0000"
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +36.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

The Perl script might need some explaining. Here's the same thing as a commented script:

```
## The . doesn't match newlines by default, so this is just a 
## quick way of getting the text before the first \n, this will be
## you variable's name.
/.*/; 
## $& is whatever was matched my the last match (//) operator. We set
## $v to that.
$v=$&; 
## Bash doesn't like dashes in variable names, this will replace
## them with underscores. 
$v=~s/-/_/g; 
## Print the variable name and its value ($foo="bar")
print "$v=\"$_\""
```

Comment: you should be careful with double quotes and evaluated input - especially where there are so many `(...)`.  it's safe enough as is, but it scares me.

Comment: @mikeserv yeah, the whole eval thing is hairy. It's possible to avoid it but that makes for some ugly shell parsing.